# The .next arrow of my slideshow disappeared after i added code for hover dropdown button in menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

The .next arrow of my slideshow disappeared after i added code for hover dropdown button in menu. The .prev arrow is still there though.

the CSS is this:

```
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}

.slide{
    display: none;
}

.prev, .next {
    color: snow;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.next {
    right: 9%;
}
```

The Javascript is this:

```
let slideindex=1;
Showslide(slideindex);

function Moveslide(n) {
    Showslide(slideindex +=n)
}

function Showslide(n){
    let i;
    let slides=document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    if(n>slides.length) {slideindex=1}
    if(n<1) {slideindex=slides.length}
    for (i=0; i<slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display="none"
    }
    slides[slideindex-1].style.display="block"
}
```

The HTMLl is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Goat</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simple-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slideshow.css">

    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: darkolivegreen;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a,
        .dropbtn {
            display: inline-block;
            color: aliceblue;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover,
        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: limegreen;
        }

        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: lightseagreen;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: aliceblue;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <!-- This content will take up 12/12 (or 4/4) of the container -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="1.CuteAnimals.html">Home Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="2.Memes.html">Memes</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="3.CutestAnimals.html" class="dropbtn">Cutest Animals</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="4.Goat.html">Goat</a>
                            <a href="5.Opossum.html">Opossum</a>
                            <a href="6.Quokka.html">Quokka</a>
                            <a href="7.Cats.html">Cats</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="8.Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">The Goat</h1>
        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/1.Goat/Goat1.jpg" alt="Goat1">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/1.Goat/Goat2.jpg" alt="Goat2">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/1.Goat/Goat3.jpg" alt="Goat3">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/1.Goat/Goat4.png" alt="Goat4">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/1.Goat/Goat5.jpg" alt="Goat5">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/1.Goat/Goat6.jpg" alt="Goat6">
            </div>
            <!--Buttons-->
            <a class="prev" onclick="Moveslide(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="Moveslide(+1)">&#10095;</a>
        </div>
        <script src="javascript/slide.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried removing the new added internal CSS for the dropdown button but nothing happened.
I also brought back the internal CCS i used when the .next arrow was apparent and it didn't appear again.